# Duplicate Values - keep one of the values

Tags: excel

I have my excel workbook sorted in colors by duplicate values.

The excel document has all of the values of the duplicates selected, how do I keep one of the values instead of completely removing all of the duplicates, including the unique value.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data? Also, how do you know which value you want to keep?

Comment: Is it something like the [Oracle COLLECT](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306) function that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

in Excel 2007:

`Data tab` >> `Remove Duplicates`

Comment: Hi Philip, that remove duplicates removes all value cells that contain duplicates, removing all. i need to keep one of the duplicates, otherwise they will be completely removed.

Comment: so if you have in a list: 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 you would want to still see 2,2,3,3?

Answer (score 1):

Just select your data/column(s) and go to Data / Remove Duplicates Or
select data and press Alt + A, M.